# How to open a pdb file in Python?

Tags: python, pdb-palm, palmdb

I've got an e-book (viewable with isilo) in a pdb file. Is it possible to read it's contents with Python (perl, ruby, php)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDB was designed for Palm pilots in the very beginning. isilo started kind of as a universal reader on PDAs so they've also implemented the PDB protocol.

For python, you can use the [Python PalmDB library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pythonpalmdb/).